# Parsing ByteBuffer in node?

Tags: node.js, bytebuffer

I have data from an api that has returned like this:

```
var body = data;
```

data is equal to:

```
ByteBuffer {
    buffer:
         <Buffer 09 62 61 1f 04 01 00 10 01 11 61 99 5d 05 01 00 10 01>,
    offset: 0,
    markedOffset: -1,
    limit: 18,
    littleEndian: true,
    noAssert: false
}
```

I've tried passing different functions to it to try to get the data from it. (I'm expecting at least 2 IDs.) Here is what I have tried so far and their results:

```
var message = body.readUint32(); // 526475785
var message = body.readCString(); // [blank]
var message = body.readUint8(); // 16
var message = body.readUint64(); // Long { low: -1721691903, high: 66909, unsigned: true }
```

I also tried:

```
var message = new ByteBuffer(8 + 8 + 4 + Buffer.byteLength(body.buffer) + 1, ByteBuffer.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
```

which returned:

```
ByteBuffer {
    buffer:
    <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>,
    offset: 0,
    markedOffset: -1,
    limit: 39,
    littleEndian: true,
    noAssert: false
}
```

I also tried passing just 'body' in but that didn't work at all. Should I be parsing this differently? What exactly should I change to get the data? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to flip the bytebuffer first to make the `ByteBuffer` ready for read operations.

After the buffer is ready for read operations, use `readIString` to read the whole buffer as a string, you can use other operations such as `readInt32` if you are expecting the buffer to be of other values than a string (I'm assuming a string since it is coming from an API).

```
body.flip().readIString();
```

A link to the ByteBuffer docs:
https://github.com/dcodeIO/bytebuffer.js/wiki/API

Comment: Thank you Bamieh, I'm actually adding a new method to an already existing API. The readISString seemed to error for me. I also tried without the flip() and similar error. I believe the number from `readUint32()` is the id of the user but I'm also looking for another ID. Is there no way to print all the data and look through it?

Comment: @JackNicholson try the `printDebug` function? do you have a toy example I can follow to be able to help you better?

Comment: This is my result from printDebug. Doesn't seem that useful :/ Sure! I'm adding a new handler to here: https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steam-user/blob/89eb29e6991251b127b4ddc211c7c415333bf92e/components/chat.js so I can detect game invites on Steam. My new handler is correctly triggered when I invite myself - it's just getting the data from it so I can tell who it's from and for what game. Here's my new code with most of my testing and comments removed: https://gyazo.com/231b3181fda8922d14c3ec313e513451

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still really stuck on this :(

Comment: Am I able to contact you personally about this? I'd be willing to pay for your help no question. I tried to PM you on Twitter but it I wasn't allowed. Really appreciate your help so far @Bamieh

Comment: @JackNicholson DMs opened now, feel free to chat no worries